# Read-Only error when saving image from URL in Android

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, urlconnection, fileoutputstream

I am trying to save an image from a web URL in an android application however when I run it, the log cat throws an exception saying its "read only". I don't know whats going on.

Here is my downloader class:

```
  public class ImageDownload {

public static void downloader(String imageURL, String fileName) { 
        try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.exampleurl.com/" + imageURL); 
                File file = new File(fileName);


                URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                int current = 0;
                while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                        baf.append((byte) current);
                }

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                fos.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Downloader", "Error: " + e);
        }

}
}
```

When I run this, this is what I get from the logcat:

```
DEBUG/Downloader(22112): Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /example.gif (Read-only file system)
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Here is my answer to a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353871/fileoutputstream-throws-filenotfoundexception-when-unzipping/15308534#15308534

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try saving to /sdcard/example.gif

Comment: Ok, perfect that solved it. It saved to /sdcard/example.gif. I just swapped out /sdcard/ with the exact location (data/data/com...) I wanted and it worked. I didn't realize I wasn't specifying the proper file location to begin with. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The directory that the `new File(fileName);` call defaults to is not writeable. To get the path to the file writing directory for the current context, you use getFilesDir(). So `new File(getFilesDir()+fileName);` equates to the usual java behaviour of opening a file in the "current" directory.

Comment: I think it should be `new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + fileName)`, otherwise you will get something like `/data/data/<apk>/files<fileName>` instead of `data/data/<apk>/files/<fileName>`.