# java.io.FileNotFoundException with FileWriter

Tags: android

The following line

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/log0.txt");
```

throws:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /log0.txt (Read-only file system)`

I'm testing this on device and "USB storage"  is off. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Try the answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315560/read-only-error-when-saving-image-from-url-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create a file in the root path "/". Try to create the file in a writable path like "/data/" or "/mnt/sdcard" or use the methods: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

See also:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure log0.txt is present in ur device. Other wise it give exception

Comment: FileWriter creates the file if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/working-with-files-t115.html) is a tutorial, which begins describing your issue. It will be helpful to read.