# FileNotFoundException in an Android app: can't find the route to copy the file

Tags: android, csv, filenotfoundexception

Good afternoon everyone,

I'm having a problem here with an CSV file that I wanna use to fill a dynamic table in Android.

I placed the file in the "data" folder of my emulator, and I did the following declaration to create my file variable:

```
file = new File("/data/Motors.csv");
```

I used a CSVReader class posted on another thread from this page ([Link to the class](http://code.google.com/p/secrets-for-android/source/browse/trunk/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.java)) and also declared the following line to do the parse:

```
readerCSV = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file),';','"',0);
```

In the last line, the programmer to be able to create the variable has to send as parameters a Reader (Or a FileReader, it doesn't make a difference), the separator char, the quote char and the number of how many lines the CSV reader has to skip.

The problem comes that no matter in which directory (Not even in the root directory, which Java tells me that it's "/" through the `file.getAbsolutePath();` method) it always gets to the point when the program throws the **FileNotFoundException** and I'm getting a bit frustrated because I have 2 days already with this problem.

If someone could please help me to get a bit of orientation of what I should do to get the file from the right directory... It would be a lot of help and I can go further with the code I have to finish.

Many thanks in advance!!!!

**EDIT**
I found a solution to open my file:

- I have used 2 file variables: one gets the rout of the External Storage Directory (see first answer in the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305801/android-filenotfoundexception)) and the other is declared as a new file, like the following lines in the code: 
  `route = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  file = new File(route,"Motors.csv");`
- Later I used again the CSV reader class that I found, where the first parameter is from the `FileReader` type (Sorry @Rajesh, but I couldn't use your alternative because you passed a `FileDescription` parameter from the `AssetManager` to the CSV reader class and then I had to change the whole class and that didn't help my problem at all).

Now I don't get the exception at all!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) in Android. Files can be stored in internal and external storages.  If the CSV file is a static resource, you could think of bundling the file in the "assets" folder of your project.

If you are using the "assets" route, the following code segment can get you a `CSVReader`.

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = am.openFd ("Motors.csv");
FileDescriptor fd = afd.getFileDescriptor();
readerCSV = new CSVReader(fd, ';','"',0);
```

The above code snippet doesn't perform error/exception handling, please remember to take care of that. You need to copy the Motors.csv file to the "assets" folder within the project.

Comment: `getAssets()` is a method of [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) of which the [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is a subclass of. Please read the documentation for more information. You have to call the method from within the Activity or pass the reference to the context to the method calling it (where you can call it as `context.getAssets()` ).

Comment: I just see that I can't use what I was doing and I have to start from scratch. I was trying to use the `getAssets()` in a class that didn't have anything to do with the class Activity. Thanks for the getAssets() tip. 

I will tell you all what I have accomplished. I used the SharedPreferences, but my idea of the CSV is that the user is able to add and modify the content of the list not using the app.