# FileOutputStream throws FileNotFoundException when UnZipping

Tags: java, android, file

I'm using a class that I found through google to unzip a .zip file.. The .zip contains files and folder. The problem is that `FileOutputStream` `throws` `FileNotFoundException`.. But the file should  be taken from     the .zip file so how can it previously exist?
Here is the code I'm using in the `AsyncTask`:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {

        String zipFile = Path + FileName;

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(Path
                        + ze.getName()); // <-- crashes here
                while ((length = zin.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    publishProgress(length);

                }

                zin.closeEntry();
                fout.close();
            }

        }
        zin.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Another `AsyncTask` which downloads the .zip:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
      try {
          URL url = new URL(params[0]);
          URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();

          conexion.connect();

          int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
          File f = new File(Path+FileName);
          if(!f.exists())
          {
              f.mkdirs();
              if(!f.createNewFile())
              {
                  f.delete();
                  f.createNewFile();
              }
          }

          InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
          OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Path+FileName);

          byte data[] = new byte[1024];

          long total = 0;

          while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
              total += count;
              publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
              output.write(data, 0, count);
          }

          output.flush();
          output.close();
          input.close();
          return true;
      } catch (Exception e)     
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getCause();
        return false;
      }
```

I get again the `FileNotFoundExcpetion` with (is a directory) message error!.

Comment: What are the contents of Path?  Could it be that it is missing a trailing `/`?

Answer (score 17):

`FileOutputStream` will throw `FileNotFoundException` if the directory(s) involved don't exist. I don't see any directory-creation code here, or even any code to check if `Path` exists, so that's probably what's going on.

Comment: But the files+folder get extracted from the .zip file.. there are a lot of files in the .zip so should I create all the files manually before extracting!! I check of dirs (dirChecker)..

Answer (score 8):

I get the FileNotFoundException again with (is a directory) message error.

```
File f = new File(Path+FileName);
f.mkdirs();
```

Try using

```
File directory = new File(Path);
directory.mkdirs();
```

and then

```
File file = new File(directory, FileName);
```

instead of your code.

Comment: Would you please tell me why this does not provide an answer to question? According to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer , I think my answer can also solve problem except it comes too late :)

Comment: This is a decent answer. If you check the timestamp when I left the message, it was after your **1st posting of this answer**. That version was poorly formatted and undirected.

Comment: @jvperrin did a great job originally editing. I suggest you study the changes he and JonathanLeffler made to your answer, enhancing it ;)

Comment: Yeah, Sorry for my poor basic markdown usage. **Enhancing :)**

Answer (score 3):

Your first version relies on `dirChecker(`) which you haven't posted, but either it doesn't work correctly, or your ZIP file doesn't contain directory entries at all, which is prefectly legal, so you shouldn't rely on them being present anyway.

Your second version is better but you don't need all this:

```
 File f = new File(Path+FileName);
          if(!f.exists())
          {
              f.mkdirs();
              if(!f.createNewFile())
              {
                  f.delete();
                  f.createNewFile();
              }
          }
```

You just need this:

```
File f = new File(Path, FileName);
f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

The rest will happen anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is caused due to zip files or directories nested within the given zip. In case the given ZipEntry is a directory, you need to create the directory and skip writing with the FileOutputStream.

use `zipEnrty.isDirectory()` to check whether the given zipEntry is a directory and create the directory using `zipEntry.mkDirs()` and proceed to the next zipEntry without writing it using fileOutputStream.

Here is the full code for unzipping a zip file :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class Unzip
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            final int BUFFER = 1024;
            int count;
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            String path="res/Example.zip";

            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
            ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new  BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream));
            ZipEntry zipEntry;

            while((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Extracting: " +zipEntry);
                File file=new File(zipEntry.getName());
                if(zipEntry.isDirectory())
                {
                    file.mkdirs();
                    continue;
                }
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new     FileOutputStream(file,false);
                bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream, BUFFER);

                while ((count = zipInputStream.read(data, 0, BUFFER))!= -1)
                bufferedOutputStream.write(data, 0, count);

                bufferedOutputStream.flush();
                bufferedOutputStream.close();
            }
            zipInputStream.close();
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

From the javadocs for the [FileOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String%29) constructor

> Throws:
>   FileNotFoundException - if the file exists but is a directory
>   rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or
>   cannot be opened for any other reason

Often, a FileNotFoundException occurs if you do not have permissions to create files or that part of the file system is read-only (though I'm not sure to what extent this applies in Android)

Comment: I'm trying to write to the external sd and I have uses-permission (Write_External_Sd..) so I can write there

Answer (score -1):

I used to write from app widget to both internal and external Android memory with following code:

```
        URL adr = new URL(cleanUrl);


        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) adr.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);

        urlConnection.connect();

        File file = new File(path, name);

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; 
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        fileOutput.flush();

        fileOutput.close();
```

Where path was both:

```
        path = mContext.getFilesDir();
```

or

```
        path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

and

```
        path.mkdirs();
```

In both cases I've got a **FileNotFoundException** and a created file with zero length.

I've **managed to write** to both types of Android memory with a following function:

```
   protected InputStream get(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        return null;
    }


    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        try {
            return entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And following usage:

```
          File file = new File(path, name);

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = get(cleanUrl);            

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {

            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        fileOutput.flush();

        fileOutput.close();
```

Comment: Nothing to do with it. The question is about ZIP files.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the "android:maxSdkVersion="18" "  from Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
   android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

You declared in Manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    />
```

Comment: Even if he had, for which there is zero evidence, you need to provide an explanation of why this would solve the problem, which it doesn't.

Comment: I  got the same issues while downloading images and videos in sd card.  so I just remove  android:maxSdkVersion="18" from manifest. its working fine.