# "Permission denied" when writing to context.getFilesDir()

Tags: android, file-io, permission-denied

The first time a user opens my app, I write a little bit of data to a local file.

I understand that my app needs permission to write to this file, so I'm using getFilesDir() like so:

```
File ins = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "INSTALLATION");
// do some things
FileOutputStream out = FileOutputstream.new(ins);
out.write(data.toString().getBytes());
out.close();
```

This works in 99.9% of cases. But I see a small trickle of exceptions saying that I don't have permission to create this file. For example:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.blah.blah.Blah
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /INSTALLATION (Permission denied)
```

Why does this happen? Can I work around it? An immediate crash is *such* an unpleasant first experience with an app.

Comment: did you solved?if yes then please accept it as answer

Comment: Here is my answer to a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353871/fileoutputstream-throws-filenotfoundexception-when-unzipping/15308534#15308534

Comment: Have you figured out what the issue was? I am having the same problem. I am using official Android code to track installation http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: did you ever find a solution? im having the same problem and the documentation states that no additional permissions are needed for this folder. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()

Answer (score -2):

Give permission in android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

make sure your giving correct path of file with extension as you are getting

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: No, that can't be right. You can write to your application's storage without asking the user for external storage access.

As I said, 99.9% of the time the writes succeed; the path & name are always the same, so it's not a permissions issue or an incorrect path.

Comment: without permission!.its amazing and against the DOC.We can write  to only Assets,Share prefreneces without permission,not to sdcard.

Comment: I'm not trying to write to the SDCard. That's a completely different issue.

I'm writing to the application's private directory, as in:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: This may be old but the above answer could be correct if the users are moving your application to the SDcard via the android apps list feature.  Just a thought.

Comment: I have the same issue and I am requesting the permission: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and yet still the result is: PERMISSION DENIED. Please answer it if you found the solution.

Comment: any solutions for this matters?