# JTar to extract files from .tar file

Tags: java, tar

I am using `jtar-1.1` to try extract files from a tar file, im using the following code to try extract the files

```
String tarFile = "c:/test/test.tar";
String destFolder = "c:/test/myfiles";

// Create a TarInputStream
TarInputStream tis = new TarInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(tarFile)));
while (( entry = tis.getNextEntry() ) != null) {
        System.out.println( "Extracting: " + entry.getName() );
        int count;
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            new File( destFolder + "/" + entry.getName() ).mkdirs();
            continue;
        } else {
            int di = entry.getName().lastIndexOf( '/' );
            if (di != -1) {
                new File( destFolder + "/" + entry.getName().substring( 0, di ) ).mkdirs();
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( destFolder + "/" + entry.getName() );
        BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream( fos );

        while (( count = tis.read( data ) ) != -1) {
            dest.write( data, 0, count );
        }

        dest.flush();
        dest.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have edited the code above to check is the `entry` a `directory` and once i done this it got rid of the `FileNotFound` error... the above code now works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to create the path before opening the FileOutputStream.

Similar Thread [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353871/fileoutputstream-throws-filenotfoundexception-when-unzipping)

Comment: Yes - this is exactly the problem.  The tar file is giving an entry which requires a subdirectory to be created under the *destfolder* directory. Check the TarEntry.isDirectory() method first, and if it is a directory, make sure to create the directory, and then skip to next entry.

Comment: Yes that was exactly it, i have edited my code above to do exactly what ye said to do and it is now working perfectly... thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just off the cuff, perhaps the issue is that the entry you are receiving contains a subfolder that hasn't been created yet: 'LAB3'?  In this case the directory 'LAB3' doesn't exist in the file system because you haven't created it and the file 'sg5' intends to be placed there so when you try to create a file on the fully qualified path that includes LAB3 it complains.

Comment: ya that was exactly what was wrong, i was not creating the directory so i was not creating 'LAB3' so it could not go any futher from there then