# How to use jackson 2.6 to produce json from objects?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I try to use Jackson 2.6 to produce a json file from the objects I created.  And I've got an error of " java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/kent/Desktop/sample.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)" in my Android Studio.

Did I miss anything in my code?

My data is as followed:

```
school id: A1, "Point Grey"
Student name: "Kent", "Age": 43
Student name: "Jane", "Age": 18
Student name: "Winnie", "Age": 19 

school id: B1, "Prince of Wales"
Student name: "Steven", "Age": 11
Student name: "Michelle", "Age": 30
Student name: "Ronald", "Age": 20
```

My Directory is as followed:

```
public class DIRECTORY {
   private Map<String, SCHOOL> schools = new HashMap<String, SCHOOL>();


    public void setSchools(Map<String, SCHOOL> schoolsMap) {
    this.schools =  schoolsMap;
    }

 public Map<String, SCHOOL> getSchools() {return this.schools;}


 public void addSchool(String schoolId, String schoolName) {
     SCHOOL school = new SCHOOL();
     school.setSchoolId(schoolId);
     school.setSchoolName(schoolName);
     schools.put(schoolId,school);

   }

    public SCHOOL getSchoolById(String schoolId) {
        schools.get(schoolId);
    }

   }
```

My School class as followed:

```
public class SCHOOL {
private String schoolId;
private String schoolName;
private List<STUDENT> students = new ArrayList<>();

//getter and setter for schoolid and school name 
public void setStudents(STUDENT students) {
    this.students = (List<STUDENT>) students;
}
public List<STUDENT> getStudents() {return this.students;}
public void addStudent(String names, String age) {
    STUDENT student = new STUDENT();
    student.setNames(names);
    student.setAge(age);
    students.add(student);
}
```

My student class as followed:

```
public class STUDENT {
private String names;
private String age;
//getter and setter for name and age

}
```

My data is as followed:

```
private static DIRECTORY createDummySchool(){

    DIRECTORY directory = new DIRECTORY();
    directory.addSchool("A1", "Point Grey");
    directory.addSchool("B1", "Prince of Wales");

    SCHOOL schoolA1 = directory.getSchoolById("A1");

    schoolA1.addStudent("kent", "43");
    schoolA1.addStudent("Winnie", "19");
    schoolA1.addStudent("Jane", "18");

    SCHOOL schoolB1 = directory.getSchoolById("B1");
    schoolB1.addStudent("Steven", "11");
    schoolB1.addStudent("Michelle", "30");
    schoolB1.addStudent("Ronald", "20");

    return directory;
}
```

My Directory List as followed:

```
public String outputDirectorylist(List<DIRECTORY> directorylist) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (DIRECTORY directory:directorylist) {
        sb.append(school.getSchoolId());
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(school.getSchoolName());
        sb.append(";");
    }

    return String.valueOf(sb);

}
```

My Main class is as followed:

```
 ....

    DIRECTORY directory = createDummySchool();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


    try{

        mapper.writeValue(new File("/Users/kent/Desktop/sample.json"), directory);


    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}
    .....
```

Comment: Do not use only CAPITAL letters in class names. SCHOOL should be School, DIRECTORY should be Directory.

Comment: usually the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353871/fileoutputstream-throws-filenotfoundexception-when-unzipping - certainly unrelated to JSON/Jackson, the path you specify (`/Users/kent/Desktop/`) is probably wrong. And in case you run this code on an Android device/emulator it is most definately wrong because there are no user home directories on those devices.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder.  Yes I am using Android studio and I use genymotion as my emulator...Is there other way I can display it and write it to a file?

Comment: You don't have to change the code, just the path to something that works: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: I am new to Android...Can you evaluate a bit further...