# How to find a path write to a json file in Android studio emulation?

Tags: java, android, jackson

I am trying use Android Studio emulation to produce a json in my apps. Is there a way to locate the directory and set it as path and implement it in the following?

```
    ......
    DIRECTORY directory = createDummySchool();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {

     mapper.writeValue(new File(filepath? + "sample.json"), directory);

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

well it depends where you want to write your file in, Internal or external memory.

you can always write information in  internal memory which can be accessible by your app but to write on external memory you will require permission like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

To save file internally you can use this

```
getFilesDir();
String filename = "myfile";
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);

String string = "Hello world!";
```

FileOutputStream outputStream;

```
try {
outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

refer this for more information, this is the best way and should be the first place where you should be looking, :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  My case is a bit difficult.  I try to use Jackson to generate json and I would like to put it in a json file in the root directory.  You can see further detail in the following link. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726394/how-to-use-jackson-2-6-to-produce-json-from-objects>.  Thanks...

Comment: you can save your file with name "anything.json" if you want, and you have already answered your question as you will be writing a JSON String to the file